# How to Insert a Row into a CSV File?

Tags: c#

Anyone know how i can insert into [Sheet1$A1:A20] my row data?

My data row i get it from the CSV Line by Line in the string[21] value.

```
string InsertCommand = string.Format("INSERT INTO [table1$A1:A1]  values('AA');");

cmd = new OleDbCommand(InsertCommand, oledbConn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

oledbConn.Close();
```

Comment: Did you try changing `[table1$A1:A1]` to `[table1$A1:A20]`? (Or `[Sheet1$A1:A20]`, if that's what you really want?)

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. Subject is about a CSV file, your question looks like Excel and you use an OleDbCommand. Where is `string[21]` in your code? Please reword and clarify your question.

Comment: My question is about the insert a string[n rows] i use oledb in the range A1:A(n rows)?    n rows is a number of my table of strings